# find all jquery input fields after the a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all the input fields when i click the a tag and input some values to those input fields

i using a **console.log** to check that what comes after i close my popup.

like here i am using the var fields = `$(this).find('input[type="hidden"]')` - Should i use `find` because it is not traversing top but bottom

all it is finding is just the anchor tag and not all hidden fields

I don't think i need to use `each` for this purpose

```
<a href="tag"></a>
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
```

Comment: Please share the HTML markup also and explain what is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: current behavior i have already stated, html is ```<a href="tag"></a>
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) to show it is finding is just the anchor tag and not all hidden fields.

Comment: could you make a html/js snippet here?

Comment: i looked at the code closesly and i see input fields are in loop and each have same class but some are hidden and some are active, so i think need to edit my question, how it will only pick the one which i clicked it, rather than pick the first one i think

Comment: Please create a [MRE] within your question. This should include the relevant HTML and JavaScript to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well we have no clue what `$(this)` is so basically impossible to answer. what is $(this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use **[`.nextAll()` method](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)** with the right selector `'input[type="hidden"]'`, it will select all the `inputs` after your `a` element:

```
$(this).nextAll('input[type="hidden"]').each(function() {
   $(this).prop("type", "text")
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("#myLink").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('input[type="hidden"]').each(function() {
    $(this).prop("type", "text")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="myLink" href="#">Click me</a>
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
<input value="1" type="hidden" class="myclass">
```

Comment: basically i solved, i was not using the fields properly

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `nextAll` <strike>and `filter`</strike>

<strike>`$('a').nextAll().filter('input');`</strike>
`$('a').nextAll('input');`

**nextAll** gets all element after the **a** tag while the parameter can filter and it displays only **inputs** from them.

Please note: If the element is inside another element this method won't find it.

PS. Thanks [cнŝdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669624/c%D0%BD%C5%9Ddk) for mentioning the parameter.

Comment: There's no need to use `.filter()` when we can just specify the selector in `.nextAll()`.

Comment: @cнŝdk I didn't knew that. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, we can always use `selectors` almost with all ´jQuery` methods including `.next()`, `nextAll()`. Indeed this is how jQuery works, it is made all around selectors :)